# How would I search text in a textview using gtk# and mono?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

I was wondering how I would search text in a textview and change the colour of it(Like syntax highlighting). I already have a basic text editor written with save/load functions.
Im using monodevelop in gtk#.

Thanks a lot --
Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use gtk api nomenclature here, there should be gtk# equivalents.

For search, GtkTextIter has a forward and backward search method, and is meant to be used with GtkTextView/GtkTextBuffer.

For syntax highlighting, you might investigate GtkSourceView, and its c# wrapper, it has all of the syntax highlighting infrastructure in place.  It's also a subclass of GtkTextView, so GtkTextIter will work with it.

Comment: can you explain how to use search methods? you just mentioned they exist

Comment: Pointing out they exist is enough in my opinion, you should be able to figure it out, but in reality, I don't use C#, so such an answer wouldn't be helpful to a C# programmer anyway.